# How does this bash script retrieve image DPI?

Tags: bash

Below is a bash script to get image information in a directory. There is no output i was just curious how the file information is being displayed/retrieved.

```
getDPI(){
    echo ${14};
}
getWidthHeight(){
    echo ${18};
}

for file in * 
do
fileInfo=$(file $file)
fileDPI=$(getDPI $fileInfo);
fileHeight=$(getWidthHeight $fileInfo);
done
```

Im curious what is displaying the file info? I see `fileInfo = $(file $file)` but what is that data being displayed? how does that work? is it metadata from the file?

Comment: That's the syntax for setting a variable to the output of a command. `file $file` executes the `file` command, and its output is put into the `fileInfo` variable.

Comment: Use `man file` to see what the `file` command does, or type `file somefilename` to see an example of the output.

Comment: Watch out - that script won't work with files with spaces in the name - look what happens on OSX when you take a screenshot... `Screen Shot 2021-03-24 at 10.26.04 am.png`

Comment: And that script doesn't look too portable ... here's the output `Screen Shot 2021-03-24 at 10.26.04 am.png: PNG image data, 1880 x 584, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced`.  Doesn't look like parameter 14 is going to have the right value.

Comment: And not everything will like that - `IMG_0061.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=11, manufacturer=Apple, model=iPhone XR, orientation=upper-right, xresolution=162, yresolution=170, resolutionunit=2, software=13.3.1, datetime=2020:04:01 12:36:57, GPS-Data], baseline, precision 8, 4032x3024, components 3`